# В bottom navigation drawer по-разному отображаются иконки

Tags: android

В bottom navigation drawer первые две иконки отображаются белым, а следующие три светло-серым. Как сделать их одинаковыми?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop_lenta);

        bottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigation.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_nav);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.action_profil:
                        fragment = new ProfilFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_shop:
                        fragment = new ShopFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_mail:
                        fragment = new MailFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_book:
                        fragment = new BookFragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.action_settings:
                        fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                        break;
                }
                final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Меню:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_shop_lenta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.halfway.yogamylife.ShopLenta">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/color"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_profil"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/profil" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_shop"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/shop" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_mail"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/mail" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_book"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/book" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/settings" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Peter Samokhin, они поочереди прыгают, а мне нужно, чтобы не прыгали

Comment: При нажатии прыгают

Comment: Peter Samokhin, иконки все одинаковые и в формате png

Comment: Попробуйте `app:itemIconTint` убрать.